# How to make JLabels that are the full size of the image icon?

Tags: java, user-interface

*How do I make my images full size and not just zoomed in on the center?*
My images are named 1-12.jpg.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
public class GuiApp extends JFrame{

  public static void main(String [] args){

     final JFrame shirts = new JFrame("T-shirts");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));

        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("T-shirts/"+i+".jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            l.setFont(l.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            panel.add(l);
        }//end of for loop

        shirts.setContentPane(panel);
        shirts.setSize(1000, 1000);
        shirts.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        shirts.setVisible(true);

  }//end of method
}//end of class
```

Comment: You're going about it backwards.  First, use a JPanel to put your t-shirt image, name, price, and whatever else you want to say about a t-shirt.  Second, put the t-shirt panels that you've created inside of a JPanel with a GridLayout.  The JLabel that holds the image will resize by itself if you use the right layout to create the t-shirt panel.  I'd suggest a GridBagLayout for the t-shirt panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make my images full size and not just zoomed in on the centre?

By this I assume you mean how do you shrink the image so that it is completely displayed in the space available on the grid?

Check out [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) (or `ShrinkIcon` depending on which meets your requirement better). This icon will dynamically resize as the size of the label changes. The `StretchIcon` allows you to scale the icon proportionally(default) or to fill the available space.

Since a `GridLayout` makes all components the same size the icons will also be the same size.

The basic code should be:

```
//JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("T-shirts/"+i+".jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
StretchIcon icon = new StretchIcon("T-shirts/"+i+".jpg");
JLabel l = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
```