# Resize picture to fit in the jpanel on the following example

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I've done this program but i need the picture in the jpanel to be resized ...not with the scrollbar.

Can somebody help me?

Here is the code:

```
public class ImageList {

private JPanel gui;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;
FilenameFilter fileNameFilter;
private JMenuBar menuBar;
DefaultListModel model; 

ImageList() {
    gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    JPanel imageViewContainer = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    final JLabel imageView = new JLabel();
    imageViewContainer.add(imageView);

    model = new DefaultListModel(); 
    final JList imageList = new JList(model);
    imageList.setCellRenderer(new IconCellRenderer());
    ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
            Object o = imageList.getSelectedValue();
            if (o instanceof BufferedImage) {
                imageView.setIcon(new ImageIcon((BufferedImage)o));
            }
        }

    };
    imageList.addListSelectionListener(listener);

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    String[] imageTypes = ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes();
    FileNameExtensionFilter fnf = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", imageTypes);
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(fnf);
    File userHome = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(userHome);



    fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override 
        public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenuItem browse = new JMenuItem("Browse");
    menu.add(browse);
    browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(gui);
            if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File eg = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                // this will be an image, we want the parent directory
                File dir = eg.getParentFile();
                try {
                    loadImages(dir);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            gui, 
                            e, 
                            "Load failure!", 
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    gui.add(new JSplitPane(
            JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
            new JScrollPane(
                    imageList, 
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER), 
            new JScrollPane(imageViewContainer)));
}

public void loadImages(File directory) throws IOException {
    File[] imageFiles = directory.listFiles(fileNameFilter);
    BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[imageFiles.length];
    model.removeAllElements();
    for (int ii=0; ii<images.length; ii++) {
        model.addElement(ImageIO.read(imageFiles[ii]));
    }
}

public Container getGui() {
    return gui;
}

public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
    return menuBar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageList imageList = new ImageList();

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Browser");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(imageList.getGui());
            f.setJMenuBar(imageList.getMenuBar());
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            f.pack();
            f.setSize(800,600);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}

class IconCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int size;
private BufferedImage icon;

IconCellRenderer() {
    this(100);
}

IconCellRenderer(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    icon = new BufferedImage(size,size,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
}

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, 
        Object value, 
        int index, 
        boolean isSelected, 
        boolean cellHasFocus) {
    Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    if (c instanceof JLabel && value instanceof BufferedImage) {
        JLabel l = (JLabel)c;
        l.setText("");
        BufferedImage i = (BufferedImage)value;
        l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));

        Graphics2D g = icon.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
        g.drawImage(i,0,0,size,size,this);

        g.dispose();
    }
    return c;
}

@Override 
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(size, size);
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) for some ideas. And because I know some one will mention it, have a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: I've try many methods, on stackoverflow topics and others, but i didn't succeed...if you could help me with a code..i will appreciat.

Comment: Instead of using an ImageIcon, you can use the [Stretch Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720997/how-to-make-jlabels-that-are-the-full-size-of-the-image-icon/29725613#29725613) which will resize the Icon base on the space available to the label.

Comment: So two fully runnable examples failed to help you solve your problem? Not sure what else we can do